# CSVを読み込もうとすると「不正なマルチバイト文字があります」というエラーが出る

Tags: r, csv

ExcelでCSV形式（UTF-8）で簡単なデータを作成（1行目が英字、以降数字）し、Rで `read.csv("ファイル名",header=T)` で読み込もうとすると

```
make.names(col.names, unique = TRUE) でエラー: 
   '<ef>ｻ<bf>area' に不正なマルチバイト文字があります 
>
```

というエラーが出ます。
調べたところ、エンコーディングの問題とあったのですが、UTF-8形式にしているので条件はクリアしているはずなのですがうまくいきません。

解決方法を教えていただけると助かります。

Comment: エンコーディングを明示的に指定してみてはどうでしょうか。`read.csv("ファイル名", header=T, fileEncoding="utf-8")`

Comment: ありがとうございます！解決しました！

Comment: `data.table`の`fread`を使ってみたらどうですか？`library(data.table); fread('ファイル名')`

Comment: @MichaelChirico 情報を書いて頂けるのはありがたいのですが、できれば回答をコメントとして投稿するのは避けて頂けると、回答として再投稿する手間が省けるので嬉しいです。詳しくはこちらのメタ投稿をご覧ください： https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1938/%E8%A7%A3%E6%B3%95%E3%82%92%E4%BF%83%E3%81%99%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%8D%E8%BE%BC%E3%81%BF%E3%81%AF%E3%82%B3%E3%83%A1%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E6%AC%84%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8F%E5%9B%9E%E7%AD%94%E6%AC%84%E3%81%AB%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6%E3%81%BB%E3%81%97%E3%81%84

Answer (score 1):

エンコーディングを明示的に指定してください。

```
read.csv("ファイル名", header=T, fileEncoding="utf-8")
```

-- [metropolisさん](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/16894/metropolis)の[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/33919/csv%E3%82%92%E8%AA%AD%E3%81%BF%E8%BE%BC%E3%82%82%E3%81%86%E3%81%A8%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8-%E4%B8%8D%E6%AD%A3%E3%81%AA%E3%83%9E%E3%83%AB%E3%83%81%E3%83%90%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E3%81%8C%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%8C%E5%87%BA%E3%82%8B#comment33426_33919)より。